# Where to change html code in Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Tags: html, css, iframe, dynamics-crm

Microsoft Dynamics CRM, custom iframe that currently has this code:

```
<div id="mainContainer" class="classname_here" style="max-width: 1900px">
```

I was able to change 1900px to 100% using stylish browser extension:

```
.classname_here {
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

I want to change this in Microsoft Dynamics CRM, is that possible?

Or is the 1900px set by Microsoft Dynamics CRM set in stone and cannot be changed?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I asked the same question in the Microsoft Dynamics CRM forum and got a bunch of examples for this from "Necdet Saritas":

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/363144/where-to-change-html-code-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm

> https://www.inogic.com/blog/2009/02/automatically-resize-the-iframe-to-adjust-to-the-form-size/
>
> https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/103395/setting-iframe-height-programmatically
>
> https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/185292/iframe-width-and-height-in-crm-2015-onpremise
>
> https://dynamicsninja.blog/2018/07/21/change-webresource-height-dinamicaly/

Marking this as solved for me:

Answer (score 1):

At onLoad event script try this:

```
var container = parent.document.getElementById("mainContainer");
if (container !== null)
    container.style = "max-width: 100%";
```

**But this is unsupported way**